# C# Request.Form["ID"] does not return correct "Input type=Range" value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, range

I have this code:

```
<div>
        <asp:DataList ID="dlRange" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow"
            OnItemDataBound="dlRange_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <hr>
                <h2>
                    <%# Eval("COMMITEENAME")%>
                </h2>
                <asp:DataList ID="dlComp" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <label for='<%#"comp" + Eval("CID")%>'>
                            <%# Eval("NAME")%></label>
                        <input id='<%#"comp" + Eval("CID")%>' type="range" pattern="[0-9]*" name='<%#"comp" + Eval("CID")%>'
                            min="0" max="10" data-highlight="true" value="" data-show-value="true" data-popup-enabled="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
            data-theme="b" />
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (BOTEntities context = new BOTEntities())
    {
        string memberID = Request.Cookies["BOTDAT"]["PersonId"];
        var comps = context.COMPETENCies.OrderBy(o => o.CID);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var col in comps)
        {
            COMPVALUE newCompVal = new COMPVALUE();
            newCompVal.CID = col.CID;
            newCompVal.C_DATE = date;
            newCompVal.MEMBERID = memberID;
            decimal compVal = Request.Form["comp" + col.CID] == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form[(int)col.CID]);
            newCompVal.VALUE = compVal;
            context.COMPVALUEs.Add(newCompVal);
        }
        int result = context.SaveChanges();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added to CompValue" + result);
    }
}
```

`Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form[(int)col.CID]);` does not return the correct value. I have about 26 input range controls on my page but the code behind bombs after at getting `compVal` for the 8th input. Any ideas?

Comment: When it "bombs" what is the error that is produced?

Comment: No error, it just exits the for loop and not hitting the next line of code.

Comment: In VS, `ctrl + alt + e` will bring up an exceptions dialog.  Check the box for `Thrown` on the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` and run it again.  If its dying, there has to be an error as to why.